# VBA issue with running "delete" SQL strings & append queries

Tags: vba, ms-access, append

I have this VBA code below, which runs on open of a form in MS Access. This code is meant to delete all records from several tables, and then run saved append queries (that are quite complex) to fill in those tables once again, with fresh data every time.

The form that opens (after this code runs) is based on the last table that gets updated in the code sequence (PDSForecast), and I have confirmed that the append query for that table works and loads the correct data in.

The issue though is, when the form based on that table is opened (which triggered this code to run in the first place), all the records show up as #Deleted for some reason, even though the append query that populates the table this form is based on is the last piece of code that runs before the form opens, and it works. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM ECIInventTransIntentDim"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM CurrentOH"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM CurrentOO"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM RequirementsAXAPTA"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM AvgWeeklyUsage"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM PDSForecast"

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query_ECIINVENTTRANSINVENTDIM"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query_CURRENTOH"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query_CURRENTOO"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query_REQUIREMENTSAXAPTA"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query_AVGWEEKLYUSAGE"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query_PDSFORECAST"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Comment: Simply requery the form: `Me.Form.Requery` after append queries.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your form is bound to the data table.  What you should do is unbind the form before the series of queries are run and then re-bind.  Your code will look similar to this:

```
frmMain.DataSource = nothing
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE ..."
... etc.
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
frmMain.DataSource = "myTable"
```